# Detect WHAT the user has changed when updating row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a setup where users can add new records to a database and then edit them.

I'm basically trying to set up a log system, where whenever any user makes a change, it logs their name at the bottom of the view page when you're viewing one of the rows currently in the database (i.e. you can see who has edited the current row at what time on what date).

Just trying to figure out a way to show WHAT they have changed, as well as when they have updated it. Basically need the code to detect what has been changed, and then print out the column name.

Update code is like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET DATE='$DATE', JOB='$JOB', ADDRESS='$ADDRESS' WHERE id='$id'";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Anyone here wants to do his homework?

Answer (score 3):

The concept is simple:

1. Fetch the row that is to be updated
2. Compare the values of that row with the new values
3. Wherever there is a difference, store it  in your log along with the current date
4. Run the update

done!

Answer (score 1):

well, you could use a trigger and a log table.
It's a pretty basic concept, go check some docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) which logs the changed values.